# Handling multiple currencies in Magento

Tags: php, magento

In Magento, we have multiple stores. Two of these stores share the same products but they have different prices. Store 1 uses Japanese Yen while Store 2 uses US Dollar. I'm using Japanese Yen as the base currency for both stores so that we don't need to input 2 prices, 1 for Yen and 1 for Dollar. I was able to convert all the prices in Store 2 frontend-wise to dollar by making some changes in the html code.

We use Paypal as the payment method. Since we use yen as the base currency the currency for Store 2 also displays as yen. I converted this also to dollar. Everything works well up to this point. The problem comes in when I go to the admin panel. Under Sales/Orders. I try to process the order and Invoice the specified order. The problem is, the order details now show 2 prices (1 in yen, 1 in dollar) like so:

> Order Totals
>
> Grand Total   ¥21,200.00
> [$218.36]
>
> Total Paid ¥0.00
> [$0.00]
>
> Total Refunded ¥0.00
> [$0.00]

So if I try to invoice the order, I end up with this error:

```
PayPal gateway has rejected request. Currency of capture must be the same as currency of authorization (#10613: Currency mismatch).
```

Is there anyway I can make Magento handle both currencies while the base currency is Japanese Yen?

Answer (score 1):

As i know paypal is not accepting Yen directly there two alternative here i can suggest you to follow this two link and i am sure you will find solution depends on that

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/270952/

follow this thread and may be you will get better idea,

however you can also go throw this Documentation to create some customization in model file to make it happen in your case

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-checkout/magento-paypal-standard-how-to-pay-with-currency-other-than-base-one-and-do-it-in-your-language/

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: Thanks. This let me change the currency but the problem when invoicing the order in the admin panel still persists. I still get the same error because the order has 2 currencies appearing.

Comment: The same as above. PayPal gateway has rejected request. Currency of capture must be the same as currency of authorization (#10613: Currency mismatch).

Comment: please go throw all step again, might be some steps you foret, i think that error could not come.

Comment: I did. The thing is from what I understood in the threads you provided, they're trying to change the currency. I got the working now the problem is Paypal is passing the currency it used to the order in the admin (backend) so when I try to invoice it, the system can't create an invoice because of the conflicting currencies. I also tried editing the order instead to change the currency but I got a server error and I do not have access to the htaccess  file.

Comment: The change in currency works but the invoicing does not work. It doesn't work at all, never has, if I used the store's current currency code in place of the base currency.